# ¿Cómo eliminar varios nodos de una lista enlazada C?

Tags: c, algoritmos, lista

Tengo esete codigo

```
_nodoFechasEspeciales *eliminarFechasEspeciales(char materia[], _nodoFechasEspeciales *apuntador)
{
    //INTENTO DE BORRAR NODO 1
    if (!listaVaciaFechas(apuntador))
    {
        _nodoFechasEspeciales *borrarAuxiliar;
        _nodoFechasEspeciales *anterior = NULL;

        borrarAuxiliar = apuntador;


        while (borrarAuxiliar != NULL && strcmp(borrarAuxiliar->nombre, materia) != 0) 
        {
            anterior = borrarAuxiliar;
            borrarAuxiliar = borrarAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }

        if (borrarAuxiliar == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nNODO NO ENCONTRADO");
        }else if (anterior == NULL)
            {
                apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
                free(borrarAuxiliar);               
            } else
                {
                    anterior->siguiente = borrarAuxiliar->siguiente;
                    free(borrarAuxiliar);                   
                }
    }

    return apuntador;
}
```

cuando lo uso me borra un solo nodo.

Pero por ejemplo tengo varias fechas especiales para calculo y quiero eliminarlas todas como podria hacer eso??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que conseguir es que el bucle recorra toda la lista y para cada elemento coincidente proceder a su borrado

Es decir, esto:

```
while (borrarAuxiliar != NULL && strcmp(borrarAuxiliar->nombre, materia) != 0)
{
  anterior = borrarAuxiliar; borrarAuxiliar = borrarAuxiliar->siguiente;
}
if (borrarAuxiliar == NULL)
{
  printf("\nNODO NO ENCONTRADO");
}
else if (anterior == NULL)
{
  apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
  free(borrarAuxiliar);
}
else
{
  anterior->siguiente = borrarAuxiliar->siguiente;
  free(borrarAuxiliar);
}
```

Lo sustituyes por esto:

```
while (apuntador != NULL)
{
  if( strcmp(apuntador->nombre, materia) == 0)
  {
    anterior->siguiente = apuntador->siguiente; 
    _nodoFechasEspeciales* borrarAuxiliar = apuntador;
    apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
   free(borrarAuxiliar);
  }
  else
  {
    anterior = apuntador;
    apuntador = apuntador->siguiente;
  }
}
```

---

**Edito**

Te respondí desde el móvil y cometí un pequeño error. Te explico:

```
_nodoFechasEspeciales *eliminarFechasEspeciales(char materia[], _nodoFechasEspeciales *apuntador) {
  // ...
  return apuntador;
}
```

La función va a devolver un puntero al inicio de la lista y ese puntero le estoy modificando para iterar sobre la lista.

La idea de devolver ese puntero es para avisar cuando la lista se quede vacía. Estos errores también se deben a que no has puesto un ejemplo compilable, luego toca resolver la duda de cabeza.

Una posible solución:

```
_nodoFechasEspeciales *eliminarFechasEspeciales(char materia[], _nodoFechasEspeciales *apuntador) {
  _nodoFechasEspeciales* ptr = apuntador;
  _nodoFechasEspeciales* anterior = NULL;
 while (ptr != NULL)
 {
   if( strcmp(ptr->nombre, materia) == 0)
   {
     if( anterior )
       anterior->siguiente = ptr->siguiente;
     else
        apuntador = ptr->siguiente; // el primer elemento de la lista se elimina         
     _nodoFechasEspeciales* borrarAuxiliar = ptr;
     ptr = ptr->siguiente;
      free(borrarAuxiliar);
    }
    else
    {
      anterior = ptr;
      ptr = ptr->siguiente;
    }
  }
  return apuntador;
}
```

Comment: Lo puse así, cuando llego a la parte que pregunto que materia quiero borrar la pongo le doy enter se queda como procesando y luego me sale segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: yo tengo inicializado anterior como NULL sera que por eso al llegar a la parte de borrar me sale segmentation fault (core dumped)??